# An issue with big amount of images - Ad Gallery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using [AD-Gallery](http://coffeescripter.com/code/ad-gallery/) plugin for my site.
When in gallery is small amount of images, everything works fine - [link](http://referer.us/http://perfectbody.pl/?p=13&idg=11).

But when in gallery is big amount of images [(here 650)](http://referer.us/http://perfectbody.pl/?p=13&idg=13) there appears an issue - after all images are loaded, they start to display in the background of page, and all is in big mess :(

I've checked it with FireBug and I think that problem is caused by jQuery script.

Can you help me with this problem? TIA

Comment: Not a answer to your problem, but you should SERIOUSLY consider splitting the pictures up. My webpage is still loading, telling me I have 688 elements to load. It's not weird that this crashes. It's simply too much.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but unfortunately I cannot influance on that, other person who is responsible for that says that it is okay :(

Comment: Well, my guess would be that there's just too much for the browser to handle so the rendering of the page crashes. If it works with few elements and it crashes with 650 elements, it's kind of natural to draw this conclusion. I'm afraid I can't help you any further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is simply too much data being loaded on the page.

As a work around you could consider either paging via buttons which make an AJAX request or by infinite scrolling, so that only a subset of 30 or so images are loaded at one time.